# R combine nx4 into nx2

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataset that has 1 factors (4 levels). However each factor level and data is currently in its own column, with a factor level label at the top (Matrix of n by 4).

To do an anova I want to change this to a n by 2 with all the factor labels in column A and all the data in column B.

I could easily cut and paste this in Excel, then back into a csv- but assume there is a way to do this with cbind.

Sample data:

```
A    B     C    D
2    4     6    8
3    5     7    9
```

What I require:

```
A   2
A   3
B   4
B   5
C   6
C   7
D   8
D   9
```

Comment: Please include samples of your data and desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `stack`:

```
stack(df) # where `df` is your data.frame
```

Answer (score 2):

`stack` is better here but also:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df)
```